# Why does PHP consider it "unsafe" to use system time zone?

Tags: php

PHP manual says:

> Since PHP 5.1.0 (when the date/time functions were rewritten), every call to a date/time function will generate a E_NOTICE if the timezone isn't valid, and/or a E_WARNING message if using the system settings or the TZ environment variable.

What security concerns come from using default system time zone?

Why does PHP consider it unsafe?

Comment: This isn't a security issue, or a matter of being unsafe.... it's a matter of making the PHP developer make a positive choice about their timezone settings rather than ignoring it and then complaining about the default behaviour

Comment: @MarkBaker The warning messages begins with `It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings`

Comment: If you're relying on server settings to provide a default, then you can get unpredictable results if those server settings aren't correctly configured; and if you've left PHP to use its default behaviour which is to use those settings... it's not going to break your code, but can give unexpected results

Comment: @MarkBaker It appears strange to me that PHP seems to be the only language asking me that I Must specify a time zone.

Comment: Perhaps it's the fact that many people criticise PHP, and its simply eliminating a particular criticism.... but why not try asking Derick Rethans (who wrote that) directly about why he made a particular design decision

Comment: @MarkBaker fair point, thank you!

Comment: @Subhanker not a duplicate, sorry. the other question does not answer from security perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is less of a worry of security issues (at least directly) using the local system timezone and more of issues reliably determining the system timezone at all. The solution, that gave you the message you are seeing, is based on the established coding convention that it's better to be explicit.

From my understanding, PHP devs have run into bugs in some underlying operating systems that had prevented reliable timezone detection in the past. The solution (after trying several) was to explicitly specify the timezone PHP should be working with.

As far as being unsafe, I believe there are a lot of scenarios where a faulty timezone could cause security issues for your application, even if not directly. Everything from transaction timestamps to session management in a multi-datacenter environment.